# How to add User control in the toolbox for C#.net for winforms by importing the dll to the reference?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have one dll of usercontrol and I add to it to the references in my project. And now I want to access this usercontrol from toolbox but it does not appear in the toolbox. And I can access them by writing code, but I want it in toolbox and want to use by just dragging it to the form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add my new User Control to the Toolbox or a new Winform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931328/how-do-i-add-my-new-user-control-to-the-toolbox-or-a-new-winform)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to right click on the toolbox, select "Choose Items.." and browse to the dll containing the control.

Comment: And added control will be located in which category like, all windows forms or common controls?

Comment: if i choose the dll from the debug folder does it point to the release dll automatically when i distribute my app?

Comment: I ran into a BadImageFormatException when try your solution. My "AutoPopulateToolbox" setting is set to "True," and I've also Reset my Toolbox

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the toolbox -> Choose items...

Answer (score 1):

Drag & Drop the dll (from explorer) to the desired category (in VS 2012).

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on empty field of toolbox and select "choose item" and then go to your project folder and select your dll file (or EXE file)

Answer (score 0):

The user control must have a default constructor. Otherwise it is not shown in the choose items pop-up. It might be also necessary to rebuild solution to add it to toolbox.

[Here is the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446429/how-to-put-a-usercontrol-into-visual-studio-toolbox)