# How to include custom derived controls into the toolbox

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I've defined a class that inherits from Datagridview. Is it possible to put this on the toolbox in Visual Studio so that I can just click and drop on the Windows Form Designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS2012 (and probably earlier version too), if you compile your solution with any class that derive from Control or UserControl, VS should add your control at the top of the toolbox automatically. But in any case, your solution had to be compiled once for the control to be selectable in the toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it its possible, right click on the toolbox and customize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example of how to do this [in this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446429/how-to-put-a-usercontrol-into-visual-studio-toolbox). You can find this topic in msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyca0t6t.aspx).