# Visual Studio custom control / UserControl not refreshing in ToolBox

Tags: visual-studio-2012, user-controls, toolbox

I use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, created a UserControl and everything went fine until I wanted to make some changes to the UserControl class, did a Clean and Rebuild several times, removed my custom control from the Form, added a again, but it is still not reflecting the changes that I have done to the UserControl's class.

The custom control and the form are in the same project, so no .dll or what so ever issue. How do I force Visual Studio to recompile the code and show the changes?

Comment: After several Cleans, Builds and Rebuilds, miraculously restarting Visual Studio did the job. :|

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [How to put a UserControl into Visual Studio toolBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446429/how-to-put-a-usercontrol-into-visual-studio-toolbox)

There are several approaches to the problem, might be a good future reference.