# Display a component downloaded from NuGet

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to insert a textbox into a window form so I chose FastColoredTextbox([this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting)). It's a **user-control** which can be used to make a textblock component that's very similar to the one in a text editor.

I've been trying to get it to work and have done everything I could with my limited knowledge (started winforms a few days ago)

After installing the NuGet package, I tried getting it to work but I am not even able to start. I need help getting started.

- I checked if it had the relevant assembly reference and it did.
- I expected a component like a button/label to appear in my toolbox which I could drag into my designer but it didn't, so I tried rebuilding and changed settings to see if it appeared in the toolbox as given **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446429/how-to-put-a-usercontrol-into-visual-studio-toolbox)**. I didn't see anything in the toolbox that I could drag and drop.
- I downloaded a sample project and went through the code. The designer.cs file had the variable and code for the textbox. I modified and pasted it into my designer.cs file thinking that it would appear in my designer. Visual Studio gave me a warning that the changes I make in the designer appear here and I shouldn't directly edit it.
- There's no documentation to display the textbox. There's documentation for syntax highlighting, code folding etc.
- I tried googling "how to use custom user-components" and I got links detialing the process of making a custom component.

If you need anymore details please let me know.
Help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: It would be great if NuGet referenced assemblies showed up automatically. Please leave a comment here so that this issue gets visibility: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3509#issuecomment-337100601

Comment: I have sunk half a week into a workaround you might find useful for the present: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3509#issuecomment-347621114

Comment: @jnm2 That's awesome. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using a nuget package (`Install-Package FCTB`), the control is in this dll:

```
Solution Directory → packages → FCTB.2.16.11.0 → lib → FastColoredTextBox.dll
```

You can add the control to `Toolbox` and drop in on the form and simply assign some text to `Text` property of control.

To add the control to toolbox, just right click on a group in `Toolbox` and click `Choose Items ...`, then from `.NET Framework Components` tab use `Browse...` button to choose `FastColoredTextBox.dll` from this path:

```
Solution Directory → packages → FCTB.2.16.11.0 → lib → FastColoredTextBox.dll
```

After choosing the dll, press OK to add `FastColoredTextBox` control to the toolbox. Then simply drop an instance on form and in code, assign a text to it's `Text` property:

```
this.fastColoredTextBox1.Text = "Some Text";
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I just found out that you can also drag and drop.